# Internet is fine, but downloads do not work

Tags: networking, performance, download

I have the following setup:

```
            +-- WLAN
            |
WAN --- ZTE Modem --- Switch --- Switch --- PC
                   |          +- PC
                   |
                   +-- Switch -- PC
```

And on all these PCs (either wired or wireless) internet (as in: browsing) works fine. Pages load quickly and when testing the speed, I get 10M down, 1M up. Which is decent for the connection.

However, on the wired machines, when downloading a file from any browser (I tried IE, Firefox and Chrome), the download stops at 300kB or so, never to recover. The problem arises in Windows 10, Windows 8 and Windows 7. A small test with Linux (Fedora 27) had no issues. Weirdly enough, when trying to download another large file (DVD ISO of CentOS), the wired Windows machines seem to download that fine.

The wireless terminals seem to be fine.

I have tried to change the MTU (to 1458, 1450, 1200 and 576), but that didn't make any difference.

Because the wireless terminals look fine, I think it has something to do with the switches, but these are unmanaged switches that have been running perfectly for many years. Also, the webpages and speedtests run normally.

What could cause this problem and how could I address it?

Comment: Are downloads from different websites also affected by this "stops at 300kB" issue? Or only one website / download in particular?

Comment: @StanleyYu I saw it at microsoft (downloading OneDrive client and Office365), but also with TeamViewer. Note that the websites (e.g. portal.office.com) worked fine.

Comment: How did you try Linux? With a live CD on one of the existing problem PCs? Can you try bypassing the switches (connect the PC directly to the ZTE modem) and test again?

Comment: @StanleyYu My laptop has Linux installed